# How can an image upload to Google Firebase be used as a trigger for executing a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using Google Firebase as my database for storing user images, I want the image upload on Firebase to trigger my python code in Google Cloud Functions which processes the uploaded image

I have tried two trigger solutions so far:

1. 'Google Cloud Storage' trigger using my Firebase bucket as the trigger, this returns the following error - "Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket xxxxx.appspot.com). Please, give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again"
2. I then attempted the "Firebase Realtime Database" trigger which seemed a more viable option, but got the following error - "Failed to configure Firebase Realtime Database trigger: unknown error, HTTP code 401"

Please note, that my Firebase project is not the same as my project on Google Cloud Platform

Comment: You can't write functions that trigger on events in different projects.

Comment: @DougStevenson this restriction should IMHO be clearly documented.

Comment: @DougStevenson, in that case, is there an easy/efficient way to integrate my two projects into one on Google Cloud Platform (GCP), potentially using the Firebase 'Blaze' plan which allows the project to be extended to GCP